# Varying/Fluctuating SSD Mobilenet Training loss using tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss, object-detection-api

While training SSD mobilenet using tensorflow object detection api, I get the following training loss:
[SSD Mobilenet Training Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykZIq.png) (click on the link for image of training loss)
I am confused as to why the training loss marked via red rectangle is so low when compared to others. Also, what could be the possible reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Apparently, my dataset was not created properly. There were some errors in the preparation of record files. After rechecking and regenerating the record files correctly, now the models are training with decreasing loss.

Comment: Can you please point out what do you mean by errors? I am having the same issues